# What does "And you" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

In a conversation appeared the phrase "**And you**" that I do not fully understand its meaning. I did not find this phrase in any dictionary. This is the context which the sentence appears:

Sophia: Hello, I'm Sophia

Lucas: Hello, Sophia. I'm Lucas

Sophia: Nice to meet you

Lucas: And you

Comment: "And you" is a shortened version of "And you also" - do you understand that?

Comment: Is "And you" synonymous with "You too" and entirely interchangeable?

Comment: "And (to meet) you."

Answer (score 2):

"And you" is used in a variety of contexts to mean that whatever the other person said is also true for "you" as well as for "me" or whoever was referred to originally. So here, Sophia says "Nice to meet you." When Lucas says, "And you", he means, "And I also think it is nice to meet you."

You can also say, "And me" or "And Bob" or some other person. Like, Al: "The company gave me a bonus". Bob: "And me", meaning, the company gave me a bonus also. Or, "Sally is annoying". "And Bob", meaning Bob is annoying too.

In most cases you could say, "You, too" instead of "And you". "And you" is somewhat more formal, but both are informal.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's a way of saying "And it's nice to meet you too".

Saying "you too" would mean the same thing here.

The meaning depends entirely on what the previous person said.